# if/else statement issues within static methods

Tags: java, conditional-statements, static-methods

```
package geometrypack;

public class Calc {
    public static double areaOfCircle(int radius) {
        if (radius <= 0) {
            System.out.println("Input cannot be a negative number.");
        }
        return (Math.PI * (radius * radius));
        
    } // areaOfCircle method
    
    public static double areaOfRectangle(int length,int width) {
        if (length <= 0 || width <= 0) {
            System.out.println("Input cannot be a negative number.");
        }
        return length * width;
        
    } // areaOfRectangle method
    
    public static double areaOfTriangle(int base, int height) {
        if (base <= 0 || height <= 0) {
            System.out.println("Input cannot be a negative number.");
        }
        return (base * height) * 0.5;
    }
}
```

So, all I'm trying to do is get each method to not return the area when printing the error message. I want it to either return the area or return the error message. I tried putting the return statement within an else statement but the method won't allow that. Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't see the problem with negative or zero dimensions.  In all of these cases, they'll still give you the correct area.  In any case, the main way to "not return a value" in the case of violating caller preconditions is to throw an exception.

Comment: I don't either, but the instructor is very picky and wants us to follow his instructions word for word or we get docked points. And he specifically wanted the class to have this error message. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: If your instructor's instructions, word-for-word, are that you have to "return an error message" then there is something very wrong, because error messages are strings and these methods cannot return strings because they are declared as type `double`. So please edit your question to make sure you have included exactly what your requirements are.

Comment: In that case, I suggest you include those instructions _word for word_ as part of your question.

Comment: Okay, I see now. Thanks for the replies, I'll do that from now on. So basically, because it's a method that returns an double, it's going to return it one way or another. But here's his instructions anyway. "A static method that accepts the radius of a circle and returns the area of the circle." and then further down the page: "The methods should display an error message if negative values are used for the circle’s radius, the rectangle’s length or width, or the triangle’s base or height."

Comment: Upon looking at the instructions, he doesn't specify that the error message can't include the area using the negative value. I was really just being OCD about it, while trying to learn something as well. But it's much clearer to me now. Thanks for the replies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should throw an exception. For example,

```
if (radius <= 0) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Input cannot be a negative number.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or put a return statement in the `if` clause after `System.out.println`.

Something like:

```
if (radius <= 0) {
   System.out.println("Input cannot be a negative number.");
   return -1.0;
}
```

Then you can check the return value of -1.0 as an error result.

Brings us back to the C programming days before there were such things as Exceptions. :)